# How to Compress image using Dropbox Lepton Node JS Package

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to use Dropbox lepton [NodeJS Package](https://github.com/whitef0x0/node-lepton) to compress images. However, when I run the below code in my NodeJS Express App, below is the error that I get.

Could someone please suggest how can I resolve this error ?

Here is the code that I am trying to run.

```
  var myLepton                 =   require('node-lepton');

  myLepton.compress('http://www.barth.com/hires/N10_JB07006.jpg',
  {
    unjailed: false,
  },
  function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("data : "+JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    console.log('Successfully compressed image');
  });
```

Below is the **error** that I get:

```
Error: Command failed: lepton -memory=1024M -threadmemory=128M http://www.barth.com/hires/N10_JB07006.jpg 51di81xl3g.lep
/bin/sh: lepton: command not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:554:12)
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install node-lepton --save` ? (changes should be visible in package.json)

Comment: Yes, I did run the command and the package is shown in `package.json` and I can see it in `node_modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved it by installing lepton manually (see [instructions here](https://github.com/dropbox/lepton)) and adding the directory where it's installed to `$PATH` (in Linux/Mac or its equivalent in Windows).

There is another problem with this code: you're assuming that you can provide a URL as your file - but compress accepts a path to a file stored locally on your machine.

You can check that lepton is installed correctly by downloading this file locally:

```
curl http://www.barth.com/hires/N10_JB07006.jpg > file.jpg
```

and running from command-line:

```
lepton -memory=1024M -threadmemory=128M file.jpg 51di81xl3g.lep
```

Basically, [that's what node-lepton is doing](https://github.com/whitef0x0/node-lepton/blob/master/index.js#L18) :)

you should see a compressed version of the jpg saved into `51di81xl3g.lep`.

Once you have this working you can go back to your code, add the logic to download the file locally before you compress it and you should be good.

Example:

```
var lepton = require('node-lepton');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
console.log("downloading ...");
var request = http.get("http://www.barth.com/hires/N10_JB07006.jpg", function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
            file.write(chunk);
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            file.end();
            console.log("file was downloaded successfully!");

            // compress
            console.log("compressing...");
            lepton.compress('file.jpg',
            {
                unjailed: false,
            },
            function(err, data){
                if(err) throw err;
                // save the compressed data into a new file
                fs.writeFile('compressed.z', data, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                }); 
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: It works!!, thank you so much. May I why you have saved the file as compressed.z, does this reduce the file size any further, how can I decompress a compressed.z file ?

Comment: @kurrodu I just named it like that for the demo - you can choose anything you like. In order to decompress you should call `lepton.decompress`. See code example here: https://github.com/whitef0x0/node-lepton

Comment: sure, you were very helpful. Thanks again.